# How do I query LDAP from C# to resolve Oracle TNS hostname while using managed ODP.NET?

Tags: c#, oracle, ldap, directoryentry, tnsnames

Further to my previous [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561952), which I managed to answer myself with [help from the Oracle forums](https://community.oracle.com/message/10819895#10817895), I now have another issue which follows on from the earlier one (provided for background).

I wish to query LDAP directly from my C# code to perform an LDAP lookup of an Oracle TNS hostname in order to get the connection string. This is normally stored in **tnsnames.ora**, and my organisation uses LDAP (via **ldap.ora**) to resolve hostnames from an LDAP server using Active Directory.

However, I am using [ODP.NET, Managed Driver Beta](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) (**Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll**) in my C# application which doesn't support LDAP as mentioned in the [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/odpmbetainstall-1696475.html) pointed to by the [Oracle forum reply](https://community.oracle.com/message/10819895#10817895) I mentioned earlier. This is why I wish to query LDAP directly from C#.

I found a way to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452531) using `DirectoryEntry` and `DirectorySearcher`, but I have no idea what to put as the parameters to `DirectorySearcher`. I have access to **ldap.ora** which is in the following format:

> # LDAP.ORA Configuration
>   # Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
>   DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTEXT = "dc=xx,dc=mycompany,dc=com"
>   DIRECTORY_SERVERS = (ldap_server1.mycompany.com:389:636,ldap_server2.mycompany.com:389:636, ...)   DIRECTORY_SERVER_TYPE = OID

But, how do I map this to setting up the LDAP query in my C# code?

Comment: what have you tried? In C#, you'll probably setup a DirectorySearcher http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in the question, I have used `DirectorySearcher`, but I have no idea what to put as the parameters to `DirectorySearcher` based on the **ldap.ora** file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by what I found in [Oracle Database Name Resolution with OpenLDAP](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/LDAP/LDAP_8.shtml), the code should look something like this:

```
string directoryServer = "ldap_server1.mycompany.com:389";
string defaultAdminContext = "dc=xx,dc=mycompany,dc=com";
string oracleHostEntryPath = string.Format("LDAP://{0}/cn=OracleContext,{1}", directoryServer, defaultAdminContext);

var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(oracleHostEntryPath) {AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.None};
var directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry, "(&(objectclass=orclNetService)(cn=ABCDEFG1))", new[] { "orclnetdescstring" }, SearchScope.Subtree);

string oracleNetDescription = Encoding.Default.GetString(des.FindOne().Properties["orclnetdescstring"][0] as byte[]);
```

Comment: This got me a little further, but no cigar just yet. I can't use `DirectoryEntry.Exists()` due to reasons outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284253. `new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ldap_server1.mycompany.com:389/cn=OracleContext,dc=xx,dc=mycompany,dc=com", "domain\\username", "password")` successfully finds the LDAP server (introducing a deliberate typo makes it fail). However, it throws a DirectoryServicesCOMException complaining about account/password. This happens regardless of the username I enter (even non-existent ones). So, what domain/username/password should I specify?

Comment: SOLUTION! I made some edits to your code. I did some searching and found this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/472540/Alternative-tnsping-utility. The `resolveldap` function on that article is exactly what I was looking for. The LDAP server supports anonymous access, so this needs to be specified on `DirectoryEntry` via `AuthenticationType`. The rest of that method is useful as it gets the LDAP servers from the **ldap.ora** file itself by parsing. So, now I have a working solution. no connection strings hardcoded and no LDAP servers hardcoded. I'll post the modified code in another Answer.

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad I was able to get you going in the right direction. Thanks for updating this with your final solution. I'm sure others will find this useful.

Answer (score 5):

Further to my second comment in the [accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14569342/197591), this is the code for performing an LDAP lookup which improves the original version I found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/472540/Alternative-tnsping-utility). And it also handles server lists in the **ldap.ora** file that includes multiple delimited port numbers.

```
private static string ResolveServiceNameLdap(string serviceName)
{
    string tnsAdminPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Apps\oracle\network\admin", "ldap.ora");
    string connectionString = string.Empty;

    // ldap.ora can contain many LDAP servers
    IEnumerable<string> directoryServers = null;

    if (File.Exists(tnsAdminPath))
    {
        string defaultAdminContext = string.Empty;

        using (var sr = File.OpenText(tnsAdminPath))
        {
            string line;

            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // Ignore commetns
                if (line.StartsWith("#"))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // Ignore empty lines
                if (line == string.Empty)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // If line starts with DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTEXT then get its value
                if (line.StartsWith("DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTEXT"))
                {
                    defaultAdminContext = line.Substring(line.IndexOf('=') + 1).Trim(new[] {'\"', ' '});
                }

                // If line starts with DIRECTORY_SERVERS then get its value
                if (line.StartsWith("DIRECTORY_SERVERS"))
                {
                    string[] serversPorts = line.Substring(line.IndexOf('=') + 1).Trim(new[] {'(', ')', ' '}).Split(',');
                    directoryServers = serversPorts.SelectMany(x =>
                    {
                        // If the server includes multiple port numbers, this needs to be handled
                        string[] serverPorts = x.Split(':');
                        if (serverPorts.Count() > 1)
                        {
                            return serverPorts.Skip(1).Select(y => string.Format("{0}:{1}", serverPorts.First(), y));
                        }

                        return new[] {x};
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        // Iterate through each LDAP server, and try to connect
        foreach (string directoryServer in directoryServers)
        {
            // Try to connect to LDAP server with using default admin contact
            try
            {
                var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + directoryServer + "/" + defaultAdminContext, null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Anonymous);
                var directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry, "(&(objectclass=orclNetService)(cn=" + serviceName + "))", new[] { "orclnetdescstring" }, SearchScope.Subtree);

                SearchResult searchResult = directorySearcher.FindOne();

                var value = searchResult.Properties["orclnetdescstring"][0] as byte[];

                if (value != null)
                {
                    connectionString = Encoding.Default.GetString(value);
                }

                // If the connection was successful, then not necessary to try other LDAP servers
                break;
            }
            catch
            {
                // If the connection to LDAP server not successful, try to connect to the next LDAP server
                continue;
            }
        }

        // If casting was not successful, or not found any TNS value, then result is an error message
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
        {
            connectionString = "TNS value not found in LDAP";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // If ldap.ora doesn't exist, then return error message
        connectionString = "ldap.ora not found";
    }

    return connectionString;
}
```

Comment: Super handy! Thought there was no hope of using the managed libraries because we use LDAP, saves me a lot of time with some new projects.

Comment: After 8 years it's code which keeps on giving. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To get you started, try:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
...

DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry();
de.Username = "username@mysite.com";
de.Password = "password";
de.Path = "LDAP://DC=mysite,DC=com";
de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
DirectorySearcher des = new DirectorySearcher(de);
```

Now you should be able to hit ldap using the DirectorySearcher (filter, findone, etc) described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: OK, but my problem is more to do with how to map the **ldap.ora** file to this C# code. What goes in 'mysite'? Do I use my Windows username and password in 'username' and 'password'? From my **ldap.ora** file, would I use "dc=xx,dc=mycompany,dc=com" where you have put "DC=mysite,DC=com"? Do I put "ldap_server1.mycompany.com" where you have put "mysite.com"? What about the port? When I call `FindAll()`, I currently get an error - "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password." But, this happens whatever I put in place of 'mysite', so it's not clear what I have wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here a more complete sample based on the other answers:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Text;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

namespace BAT
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string directoryServer = "myServer:389";
            string defaultAdminContext = "cn=OracleContext,dc=world";
            string serviceName = "MYDB";
            string userId = "MYUSER";
            string password = "MYPW";

            using (IDbConnection connection = GetConnection(directoryServer, defaultAdminContext, serviceName, userId,
                    password))
            {
                connection.Open();

                connection.Close();
            }

        }

        private static IDbConnection GetConnection(string directoryServer, string defaultAdminContext,
            string serviceName, string userId, string password)
        {
            string descriptor = ConnectionDescriptor(directoryServer, defaultAdminContext, serviceName);
            // Connect to Oracle
            string connectionString = $"user id={userId};password={password};data source={descriptor}";

            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
            return con;
        } 

        private static string ConnectionDescriptor(string directoryServer, string defaultAdminContext,
            string serviceName)
        {
            string ldapAdress = $"LDAP://{directoryServer}/{defaultAdminContext}";
            string query = $"(&(objectclass=orclNetService)(cn={serviceName}))";
            string orclnetdescstring = "orclnetdescstring";

            DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapAdress, null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Anonymous);
            DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry, query, new[] { orclnetdescstring },
                SearchScope.Subtree);

            SearchResult searchResult = directorySearcher.FindOne();
            byte[] value = searchResult.Properties[orclnetdescstring][0] as byte[];

            if (value != null)
            {
                string descriptor = Encoding.Default.GetString(value);
                return descriptor;
            }

            throw new Exception("Error querying LDAP");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to believe I'm the first person to use this after 4 years.  Thanks, it helped a lot!